# Chrome pop-up and redirect permissions are set to block by default and that blocks the payment pop-up from opening

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

Is there a way prompt the user to allow these permissions or have the default permission changed

Comment: Unwanted popups are blocked by most modern browsers, but what exactly are you talking about regarding redirects? I don’t know of any browser that would block those by default.

Comment: I am working with an API by flutterwave payment gateway  and I need to redirect when I have sent a request and a success result is returned. But for some reason it gets blocked. Let me inspect my browser settings

Comment: And …? Still no clue what your actual problem is. Please go read [ask]. Again, not aware of any browser blocking redirects in default settings. And AFAIK there is no explicit “permission” for this either, that would trigger actively asking the user - they either have their browser set to automatically follow redirects, or they don’t. Plus, what popup are you talking about now? Such payment gateways usually use either popups _or_ redirects in my experience, so please make an attempt to explain yourself properly now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think i have encountered this issue before with flutterwave payment gateway but if you are experiencing the issue on your chrome browser you can try the steps below to allow pop-up and redirects:

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click More More and then Settings.
- At the bottom, click Advanced.
- Under 'Privacy and security', click Content settings.
- Click Pop-ups and redirects.
- At the top, turn the setting to Allowed or Blocked.

See this [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB) for more help.